# How to use https in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, https

I'm developping a webapplication. For the security of the users information i need a https connection. I'm developping this local at the moment. I have followed the tutorial on: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/25/requiring-ssl-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx

When I build my project the page loads but the url is: http://...

In my code i have placed:

```
    [RequiresSSL]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //var model = Adapter.EuserRepository.GetAll();

        return View(db.Eusers.ToList());
    }
```

code from site:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace extranet.Helpers
{
    public class RequiresSSL: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            HttpResponseBase res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            //Check if we're secure or not and if we're on the local box
            if (!req.IsSecureConnection && !req.IsLocal)
            {
                var builder = new UriBuilder(req.Url)
                {
                    Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps,
                    Port = 443
                };
                res.Redirect(builder.Uri.ToString());
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }


    }
}
```

What am i missing that the url isn't https based? Is this because I'm working local?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter checks to see if the request is local with this statement: `&& !req.IsLocal`. If it is, then it doesn't redirect. If you remove that statement then you'll be required to access the action via HTTPS regardless if you're local or not.

Comment: wow... how could i not see that *shame*, when i remove that piece of code then i get a 401 - can't make connection with the server localhost, but the link is https now...

Comment: Did you install a (test)certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> when i remove that piece of code then i get a 401 - can't make
>   connection with the server localhost, but the link is https now

Removing that part of the code is only part of the solution to your problem. Going back to your original question of **"how you can use https"** then you need to [enable it using this guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx).